# Factory boy to select from existing flask_sqlalchemy table with Iterator using parameter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, factory-boy

There are lots of great answers here, but I can't quite find the one to solve my problem.

Two SQLAlchemy models: Calendar and Transaction. Transactions link to the Calendar model:

```
class Calendar(Model):
    calendar_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    cal_date = db.Column(db.Date, unique=True, nullable=False)

class Transactions(Model):
    transaction_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    transaction_date = Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    transaction_calendar_id = reference_col('calendar', pk_name='calendar_id')
    transaction_calendar = relationship('Calendar', backref=db.backref('transaction_dates'))
```

Then Factory Boy classes to generate SQLAlchemy objects:

```
class CalendarFactory(BaseFactory):
    calendar_id = Sequence(lambda n: n)
    cal_date = Sequence(lambda n: datetime.date(2021,1,1) + relativedelta(days=n))

    class Meta:
        model = Calendar
        sqlalchemy_get_or_create = ('cal_date', )
        
class TransactionFactory(BaseFactory):
    transaction_date = Sequence(lambda n: datetime.date(2022,1,1) + relativedelta(days=n))
    transaction_calendar = SubFactory(CalendarFactory, cal_date=SelfAttribute('..transaction_date'))

    class Meta:
        model = Transactions
```

The trouble I'm having is that when my `TransactionFactory` is generated, it tries to generate a CalendarFactory object **even when there is already one for the given date**, and I get the following error:

```
(sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: calendar.cal_date
```

I've tried a number of strategies including `StaticFactory` as describe in [Avoiding duplicates with factory_boy factories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147115/avoiding-duplicates-with-factory-boy-factories)

The solution I'm trying to work on now is described in [Choosing from a populated table in factory boy while using flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69608906/choosing-from-a-populated-table-in-factory-boy-while-using-flask)

This is what I'm trying, but it ain't working:

```
def lazy_calendar(cal_date):
  """Turn query into a lazily evaluated generator"""
  yield from Calendar.query.filter_by(cal_date=cal_date).all()

class TransactionFactory(BaseFactory):
    transaction_date = Sequence(lambda n: datetime.date(2022,1,1) + relativedelta(days=n))
    transaction_calendar = LazyAttribute(lambda c: lazy_calendar(c.transaction_date))
```

***Question:*** can I call a Factory Boy `Iterator` with a parameter so I can get back the generator with the single date that I want?

Or am I completely barking up the wrong tree here?

*Note: this issue has only come to light when I'm running unit tests simulatenously via VS Code Testing feature. When I run my tests sequentially via pytest, it's fine. But I would like to get the multithreaded version working if poss.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, no responses, but after some time away I've been able to fix it myself. As often happens with specific scenarios, I'd followed a path and ended up in an overly complex knot. The solution was to start from the beginning and simply.

The key mistake was to generate the id in the `CalendarFactory` object. This allowed for the creation of multiple `Calendar` objects with the same `cal_date`.

I stopped using the `StaticFactory` and hey presto! Green ticks across the board.

So working code is:

```
class CalendarFactory(BaseFactory):
    cal_date = Sequence(lambda n: datetime.date(2021,1,1) + relativedelta(days=n))

    class Meta:
        model = Calendar
        sqlalchemy_get_or_create = ('cal_date', )
```

Thanks!

You're welcome.